# Create a new objectClass in order to add a custom attribute to an existing objectClass

Tags: ldap

Long titles ask for short answers :)

I have a ldap server with the default schemas. Under some organizational unit I have entries that have the structural objectClass *person* and another two clasess *uidObject* and *top*.

I need to add an attribute to these entries called enabledServices and I want to store in it each service that the particular person has access to ( mostly for vpn ).

From what I understood so far, I can create a new objectClass that has only one attribute and I can add that class to my entries. My question is how I create such a class ?

My set-up involves slapd and phpldapadmin on an ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a objectClass by adding a schema to OpenLDAP, schemata are documented at [OpenLDAP schema documentation](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/schema.html).

Please note:

- Once written the schema file, I would be surprised if it could be added to directory with phpldapadmin. I would recommend the command line tools;
- the examples in the documentation are in the old config format: you should convert them to the newer conf.d ldif format.

Comment: regarding the conversion I believe this document helps a lot so I figured I should share http://www.cyrill-gremaud.ch/linux/how-to-add-new-schema-to-openldap-2-4